# GNU tar's "transform" option behaves inconsistently when pattern ends in "/"

Tags: regular-expression, gnu-tar

I have come across the following strange behavior of GNU `tar` when using the `--transform` option to transform path elements: When I try to `tar` an entire sub-directory and want to transform the path to this directory, the transformation is *not* applied to the directory itself, but only to its content, when the transformation pattern explicitly contains the `/`.

To reproduce:

- create a directory `test-dir` with dummy content:

  ```
  $ mkdir test-dir
  $ touch test-dir/test{1..50}.txt
  ```
- `tar` this directory with renaming of `test-dir/` to `transformed-dir/`, and instruct `tar` to print the transformed names for checking:

  ```
  $ tar --transform="s,^test-dir/,transformed-dir/," --show-transformed-names -cvf test.tar test-dir
  test-dir/
  transformed-dir/test25.txt
  transformed-dir/test29.txt
  transformed-dir/test47.txt
  ...
  ```

As you can see, the directory itself is *not* renamed correctly, although the renaming works for all files within the directory.

- For comparison, use the same transformation but *without* the trailing `/`:

  ```
  $ tar --transform="s,^test-dir,transformed-dir," --show-transformed-names -cvf test2.tar test-dir
  transformed-dir/
  transformed-dir/test25.txt
  transformed-dir/test29.txt
  transformed-dir/test47.txt
  ...
  ```

Now, the directory itself *is* correctly renamed.

The behavior doesn't change when the `^` anchor is omitted, and is independent on whether the directory to be tarred is specified with or without trailing `/` on the command line.

- I wondered if the problem was that when the `/` is specified, in case of the directory the *entire* filename is subject to replacement. However, when specifying a transformation that would rename an entire file, that works correctly:

  ```
  $ tar --transform="s,^test-dir/test29.txt,transformed-dir/file.txt," --show-transformed-names -cvf test3.tar test-dir
  test-dir/
  test-dir/test25.txt
  transformed-dir/file.txt
  test-dir/test47.txt
  ...
  ```

So it really seems that the trailing `/` is the problem. Is this a feature, a bug, or did I somehow misunderstand the scope/syntax of the option? The `tar` version is GNU tar 1.28.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in comments by @muru and @UncleBilly, the problem here was likely a mixture of a misconception and unfortunate output by GNU `tar`.

- When run in "verbose" mode (`-v`), (GNU) `tar` will append a trailing `/` to all entries that refer to directories rather than files.
- However, the `/` is of course *not part of the actual directory name* as stored in the filesystem data.
- The transformation seems to apply to the "actual" name of the directory entry, which *does not* match the pattern `some_name/` as the `/` is not part of the name.

So the seemingly inconsistent behavior of the `--transform` option results from the difference in the *printed* directory name vs. the actual (and internally used) directory name.

As noted by @UncleBilly, if you want to ensure that only directories which fully match the specified name should be renamed, a transform statement like

```
--transform='s,^path/to/dir\($\|/\),newname\1,'
```

will ensure that only the directory `path/to/dir` (where the end-of-string anchor `$` applies) and its contents `path/to/dir/fileXXX.yyy` (where `dir` is immediately followed by a `/`) are renamed. The back-reference `\1` in the replacement text will ensure that the `/` is not omitted when transforming the path names of files inside the directory.